# Redundant data in update statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, sql-execution-plan

Hibernate generates `UPDATE` statements, which include all columns, regardless of whether I'm changing the value in that columns, eg:

```
tx.begin();
Item i = em.find(Item.class, 12345);
i.setA("a-value");
tx.commit();
```

issues this `UPDATE` statement:

```
update Item set A = $1, B = $2, C = $3, D = $4 where id = $5
```

So columns `B`, `C`, `D` are updated, while I didn't change them.

**Say, Items are updated frequently and all columns are indexed. 
Does it make sense to optimize the Hibernate part to something like this?**

```
tx.begin();
em.createQuery("update Item i set i.a = :a where i.id = :id")
    .setParameter("a", "a-value")
    .setParameter("id", 12345)
    .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```

What confuses me most is that the `EXPLAIN` plans of the 'unoptimized' and the 'optimized' query version are identical!

Comment: Obviously not all JPA implementations would issue such a statement; DataNucleus for example knows which fields are modified, and hence only includes those in the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Due to [PostgreSQL MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html), an `UPDATE` is effectively much like a `DELETE` plus an `INSERT`. With the notable exception of toasted values - see:

- [Does Postgres rewrite entire row on update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702686/does-postgres-rewrite-entire-row-on-update/22703131#22703131)

(And minor differences for heap only tuples - `DELETE` + `INSERT` starts a new HOT chain -  but that has no bearing on the case at hand.)

To be precise, the "deleted" row is just invisible to any transaction starting after the delete has been committed, and vacuumed later. Therefore, on the database side, including index manipulation, there is in effect **no difference** between the two statements. (Exceptions apply, keep reading.) It increases network traffic a bit (depending on your data) and needs a bit of parsing.

I studied HOT updates some more after @araqnid's input and ran some tests. Updates on columns that **don't actually change the value make no difference** whatsoever as far as HOT updates are concerned. My answer holds. See details below.

This also applies to toasted attributes, since those are also not touched unless the values **actually change**.

**However**, if you use **per-column triggers** (introduced with pg 9.0), this may have undesired side effects!

I quote [the manual on triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> ... a command such as `UPDATE ... SET x = x ...` will fire a trigger on
>   column `x`, **even though the column's value did not change**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Abstraction layers are for convenience. They are useful for SQL-illiterate developers or if the application needs to be portable between different RDBMS. On the downside, they can butcher performance and introduce additional points of failure. I avoid them wherever possible.

#### HOT (Heap-only tuple) updates

Heap-Only Tuples were introduced with [Postgres 8.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/release-8-4-9.html), with important improvements in [8.3.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/release-8-3-4.html) and [8.4.9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/release-8-4-9.html).
[The release notes for Postgres 8.3:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/release-8-3.html)

> `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s leave dead tuples behind, as do failed `INSERT`s.
>   Previously only `VACUUM` could reclaim space taken by dead tuples. With
>   HOT dead tuple space can be automatically reclaimed at the time of
>   `INSERT` or `UPDATE` **if no changes are made to indexed columns**. This
>   allows for more consistent performance. Also, HOT avoids adding
>   duplicate index entries.

Emphasis mine. And "no changes" includes cases where columns are updated with the same value as they already hold. I **actually tested**, as I wasn't sure.

Ultimately, the extensive [README.HOT in the source code](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD) confirms it.

Toasted columns also don't stand in the way of HOT updates. The HOT-updated tuple just links to the same, unchanged tuple(s) in the toast fork of the relation. HOT updates even work with toasted values in the target list (actually changed or not). If toasted values are changed, it entails writes to the toast relation fork, obviously. I tested all of that, too.

Don't take my word for it, see for yourself. Postgres provides a couple of [functions to check statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html). Run your `UPDATE` with and without all columns and check if it makes any difference.

```
-- Number of rows HOT-updated in table:
SELECT pg_stat_get_tuples_hot_updated('table_name'::regclass::oid)

-- Number of rows HOT-updated in table, in the current transaction:
SELECT pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_hot_updated('table_name'::regclass::oid)
```

Or use [pgAdmin](https://pgadmin.org). Select your table and inspect the "Statistics" tab in the main window.

Be aware that HOT updates are only possible when there is room for the new tuple version on the same page of the main relation fork. One simple way to force that condition is to test with a small table that holds only a few rows. Page size is typically 8k, so there must be free space on the page.

Comment: The heap-only tuples feature introduced around 8.4 actually does optimise UPDATE compared to DELETE+INSERT, since it keeps the index entries pointing the the old version of the row instead of creating new ones. Presumably that depends on the column list in the UPDATE statement to know if the UPDATE can create a heap-only tuple or not. If so, always sending the values for all columns would mean that heap-only tuples were never created for tables that have any indices  other than the primary key.

Comment: So you mean update of A will cost me update on index(A), index(B), index(C) and index(D)?

Comment: @araqnid: I have spend over an hour investigating and testing, as I your comment very interesting (+1). Turns out, HOT updates are not impaired in such a case. The behavior depends on columns **actually changed** and not so much on the column list in the `UPDATE` statement. See my amended answer for details.

Comment: ah yes, that is the case. odd that it works one way for HOT and a different way for triggers. You can see the effect using the pageinspect extension too, here's a script to demo that: https://gist.github.com/1298358

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I was reading your answer and had a question: if we update a non-indexed big text column (which uses TOAST), is the update HOT or not?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Good question. It's HOT (if other preconditions are met). I updated the answer with more info.

Answer (score 4):

You can use hibernate annotation @Entity:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
public class Item
```

This will update only the changed fields.

Comment: This varies from case to case. Hibernate documentation (http://tinyurl.com/6e6r7yz) recommends you to check performance impact in your particular case: 

_The dynamic-update and dynamic-insert settings... can increase performance in some cases, they can actually decrease performance in others._

Comment: Google says dynamicUpdate will cost extra CPU to generate SQL for statement, because statements are not cached any more :(

Comment: I think there is a trade-off between overhead on the database side and on the Hibernate side. But as always, you should measure it for your application.