# "In place" updates with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

We have a table with relatively large rows (10-40kb) and we have to update a single integer column in this table quite frequently.

As far as I know, an `UPDATE` in PostgreSQL is a transaction of `DELETE+INSERT` (due MVCC).

That's mean PostgreSQL will delete and re-insert the entire row, even if I want to update just a single integer (not requires additional space).

I would like to know if it's possible to perform an `UPDATE` operation "in place" without deleting and re-inserting rows?

Comment: You need a HOT-update: http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/site/html/misc/hot.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Postgres rewrite entire row on update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702686/does-postgres-rewrite-entire-row-on-update)

Comment: Maybe factor out heavily updated columns to a new table? Or first confirm that the current state is a problem - the db system is continously being optimized.

Comment: @FrankHeikens HOT is only of limited utility for wide rows because you can only do a HOT update where there's space on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Only fields stored in-line need to be copied. For fields stored out-of-line in TOAST tables, only the reference to the TOAST entry is copied.

Whether a field is stored out-of-line depends on the size of the value in the field and on the field's data type.

If the tuples are large but only have a few fields - like

```
some_id integer,
frequently_updated integer,
charblob text
```

then there's not much point changing anything because updates of `frequently_updated` won't generally rewrite the data in `charblob`, at least if it's big enough that it's worth caring.

OTOH, if you have a table with lots of fields you'll be rewriting a lot more with each update.

HOT will only help you to a limited extent because a HOT update can only happen when no updated column(s) are part of an index *and* there's enough free space on the same database page. For wide rows you won't fit many copies on a page even with TOAST, so HOT will be of limited benefit.

It can be worth separating such fields out into separate tables if they're really frequently updated but the rest of the table has wide rows that don't change much.